# 'module' object has no attribute 'unescape'

Tags: python

This code works perfectly on the console but when I implement it in my flask application it says that there's an `AttributeError`

```
        clean = html.unescape(tweet.text)

        final = re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', clean)
```

I also tried `import html` inside the for loop

and `from html import unescape`

Comment: `import html; print(html.__file__)` -- I bet you're fighting an implicit relative import of the `html` module.

Comment: What is your file named?

Comment: @jared-goguen manage.py

Comment: I was hoping you would provide us with the stack trace?

Comment: @Blacksun What is the name of that other file you created named 'html.py'?

Comment: @Blacksun Or, if that's not the case, which version of Python are you running?

Comment: @jared-goguen No it was a random name, it's test_amp.py The problem is with the module import in flask

Comment: I'm sorry guys my flask app is running Python 2.7. Sorry!!

Comment: @jared-goguen You're right the file was built with Python 3. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [html](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.html) module was introduced in Python 3.4. If you're running Python 2.7, you might want to try `HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape` instead.

Comment: It needs to be `HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape` (with parentheses) as in @Blacksun 's answer

Answer (score 10):

Please note that `HTMLParser.unescape` was removed from Python since version 3.9.0a1.

**Update (due to popular demand)**

Beginning with Python 3.4 you can use `html.unescape`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html

Comment: with no replacement? (Can't find in the documentation a notice on this removal). Actually, I still see it in py3.10 https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/html.html

Comment: @borgr Thanks so much! `HTMLParser.unescape` was removed with Python 3.9.0.a1 - I am very sorry! I will update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 6):

The flask app is built using Python2:

```
import HTMLParser
HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape('Hello &amp; World')
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to figure out!! I kept trying python 2.7 and 3.9, but the base interpreter should be python 2!!!

Answer (score 1):

Summing up all the answers. If you use python of version > 3.9 HTMLParser doesn't work. From py 3.4 html does work.
use:

```
import html
```

If you use python <3.4 (including 2.X) html doesn't work:

```
import HTMLParser
html = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
```

If you want compatibility to both:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] > 3:
  import html

else:
  import HTMLParser
  html = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

html.unescape(my_string)
```